# Sharepoint JSON [$Author.email] == '@me' is not working

Tags: json, sharepoint

Been doing a Sharepoint list, for some documents to go in diffrent "states" by each member of our team it have gone through.

i have a button that should be displayed, if the current user is equal to the author.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Kzq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the visibility property as following(note the brackets between two conditions):

```
"=if((@me== [$Author.email] && [$Status]== 'Draft') || (@me== [$Author.email] && [$Status]== 'RedoDraft') , 'visible', 'hidden')"
```

Comment: Thanks needed to do the single quotes on the '@me'  but i did the trick! :)